# ajax toolkit error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am using this code in asp.net 4.0:

```
 panel = $('#<%= Panel1.ClientID %>')
 panelBounds = CommonToolkitScripts.getBounds(panel); // error here
```

where panel1 is asp.net panel

and getting this error

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.ArgumentException: Value must be a
>   DOM element. Parameter name: element

How to fix this? also, Is there any alternative of getbounds in jquery to hold height width X and Y location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('xxx')` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM object. To get a DOM ref just use:

`panel = document.getElementById('<%= Panel1.ClientID %>');`

Use .positon, .width, .height in jQuery.